Stuck in step 1 typo3 v13 installation
I'm trying to install typo3 CMS, and I'm struggling on step 1. Even if the CMS says "no problems detected", I cannot go to step 2.
When I'm clicking on "Continue with installation", nothing happen. I can see a query on http://typo3.test/typo3/install.php?install[action]=executeEnvironmentAndFolders but this query returns {"success":false,"status":[]} without any details.
There is nothing on apache/php error logs, and I checked all system requirements, everything seems good to me.
I tried Typo3 v12, it works. I tried remove and redownload typo 3 V13, same thing...
Do you have any clue ?

The behavior was reproducible for me and seems to be a bug.
Could you please open an issue for that? https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues/new
Since v12.1, you can setup TYPO3 CLI: ./vendor/bin/typo3 setup- that's still doing well.

Yes, I created an account on the ticket manager, I have to wait 3 days before my account is manually validate. Hope things are going to be easier with this CMS when this will be solved :-\

I had to create the folder "typo3conf" in "public" myself - after that I could continue the installation.
(composer Installation on CloudHosting at JWeiland)

Found out it was caused by the composer create-project command which generate a public folder. When I'm downloading the typo3_src_tgz from https://get.typo3.org/13.2.1, the install is running as expected.
Don't know why, but it's working now...

Had the same problem in ddev environment. Creating this folder worked for me as well.

I created a thread in the typo3 forum : https://talk.typo3.org/t/typo3-v13-unable-to-start-a-fresh-install-with-composer/5838
Not alone in this case...
